# postgres skip row if Foreign Key is referenced

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to delete a list of rows from table "users", some user_ids are referenced as FK in user_plan table. What I want to skip the delete in "for loop" I.e handle the error

```
x= [1,31,32,33,34]
for i in x:
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%s", (str(i),))

>>>psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: update or delete on table "user_plan" violates foreign key constraint "user_fk_id" on table "user_plan"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "user_plan".
```

How can I modify the query so it will skip the delete if the FK is used somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE id IN (1,31,32,33,34)
```

you can simply do it by :

```
values = ",".join(x)
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%s", (values,))
```

i am using it in PHP, give it a try in python, it should word.

Comment: what is the error?? another question : you want to delete what is in `x` list or to skip?

Comment: and how did you get the x value too?

Comment: no, if it used in the other table then simply skip it

Comment: yes, i mean from the other table you can use `join` to join the second table it will be easy if the condition is simple just reverse it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to translate to your obsurfication layer (psycopg2), but with straight SQL you can add the predicate "*and not exists (select ...)* to the where clause. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e6643fe2dcf1cb470e915407a839c5b8).

```
delete 
  from users u 
 where u.user_id = any('{1,31,32,33,34}')
   and not exists ( select null 
                       from user_plan up 
                      where up.user_id = u.user_id
                   );
```

The above is based on assumption that by "*FK is used somewhere else*" you specifically mean the table user_plan. If there are other tables with FK to users then you need to include a *not exists * predicate for each.